# How do you prove that an algorithm works?

Tags: algorithm

TL;DR: How do I prove an algorithm will work for every value of n?

Overview:

I'm a self-taught programmer with a math background up to linear algebra. I recently needed to prove that a relationship was recursive by writing an algorithm to solve the problem for n=100.

When I got to the solution, the way that I arrived there was deemed unacceptable. The person I was speaking with said that my algorithm was a "statistical' algorithm rather than actually demonstrating that a recurrance relation existed and proving my algorithm will work.

I've been solving some problems on websites such as codesignal, hackerrank, etc., but this is the first time that I've run into this concept of generalising a solution into a formal proof.

Question:
How do I prove an algorithm will work for every value of n?

Example:
Let's use binary search as the example and just forget the actual problem that I faced.

In the case where you have an array of 100 integers, sorted in ascending order, how can you prove your binary search algorithm will work for any array and any n?

In the example below, let's say our array is

```
arr = list(range(100))
```

and my proposed problem is:

> Write a recursive algorithm that will return True if the value '42' is in the array and False otherwise.

How can you prove (as in formal proof) that this algorithm works? Please take care to highlight the thought process and intuition behind the moment that the algorithm goes from being a heuristic solution to being a proved algorithm?

Comment: You mean, any *sorted* array, right? Also, when you say '42' -- just to check, you mean the numeric value, not the string?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, nor is it really specific enough for this site.  You might try http://cs.stackexchange.com, but you'd probably be better advised to read up on something like Knuth's [The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) which contains many informal and formal proofs, including (IIRC) one for this very problem.

Comment: Also this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117078/proof-of-correctness-of-binary-search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 42 is not discarded

If an array `A` is sorted, then if we can show that `A[x] > 42`, then `A[x + 1] > 42`. This is because, if an array is sorted, each element is greater-than or equal to its predecessor (that is, `A[x + 1] > A[x] > 42`). We know this because the `>` operator is transitive.

The same is true, in reverse, for the `<` operator.

A binary search shall, at each step, reject all the inputs that are either bigger -- or smaller -- than the desired input, by sampling a single possibility, and deciding that all those on one side of it are also in need of rejection (as explained above).

(EDIT: if `x > 42` or `x < 42` is true; then `x = 42` must be false.)

## The array gets smaller

At each step, at least one element of the array is removed, unless it is equal to 42. This is because if the element is not 42, then that element (perhaps along with some others) will be removed.

If the array is getting smaller (assuming 42 is at no point sampled), and 42 is never removed, then at some point, either 42 will be sampled, or the array will be empty

## Conclusion

If the array is empty, and since 42 is not discarded, there was never a 42.

If we sample a 42, since no new elements are introduced to the array, the 42 was there to start with.

Proof!

## Additional Comments

To show that the recursive algorithm works, you want to show that it

1. ends
2. yields the correct result.

It ends because at each recursive step the array is getting smaller (but cannot dip below []). It yields the correct result because 42 is never removed nor added -- so at the end, if we can't find a 42, it's because it was never there. Your argument should not rely on any concrete examples, except maybe the base case, in my opinion--else it might be statistical. You need to "prove" it in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple correctness proof: You need to prove that your algorithm can successfully do what it is designed for.

So, take a precondition of the statement about input case data. And work out that it should imply the post condition which is required in the output. This proves that algorithm is correct.

P: Statement about given input

Q: Statement of the required output.

Prove P implies Q.

Take care of corner cases.
Make sure about the termination of algorithm in all cases.
If its a recursive algo, you strictly need to prove the algorithm terminates/exits.

> Write a recursive algorithm that will return True if the value '42' is
>   in the array and False otherwise.

For such problems, you can also use *Proof by contradiction*. First try to assume that **the algorithm will yield true if 42 is not present** or **the algorithm will return false if 42 is present**. Then, justify your assumption through your algorithm flow and try to show that this is not possible, a contradiction.

Comment: I really like this explanation. Proof by contraction was also mentioned. So to give a concrete example, what if the sorted array contained a billion items? How do you prove it is recursive so you simply make the jump to proving the algorithm exists? At what point does your demonstration of the recursive nature problem transition from a "statistical algorithm" to a proved algorithm? Does that question make sense?

Comment: To show that the recursive algorithm works, you want to show that it (1) ends; (2) yields the correct result. As in my answer, it ends because at each recursive step the array is getting smaller (but cannot dip below `[]`); and it yields the correct result because `42` is never removed nor added -- so at the end, if we can't find a 42, it's because it was never there. Your argument should not rely on any concrete examples, except maybe the base case, in my opinion--else it might be statistical. You need to "prove" it in the mathematical sense.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, @Max. Can you add your comment to your answer and I'll accept it? Thanks, Kaidul Islam, really appreciated your answer also.